# MVC pattern with AJAX calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is a weird question about a php mvc pattern with ajax calls. The purpose is make a better and dynamically web apps. Let me explain you:

When I learn php, I used this pattern specifically :

model.php

```
<?php
class myClass {

    private $attrOne;
    private $attrTwo;

    public function getAttrOne() {
        return $this->attrOne;
    }

    public function setAttrOne($attrOne) {
        $this->attrOne = $attrOne;
    }

    public function getAttrTwo() {
        return $this->attrTwo;
    }

    public function setAttrTwo($attrTwo) {
        $this->attrTwo = $attrTwo;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------

    public function doSelect() {
        //some code
    }

    public function doInsert() {
        //some code
    }

    public function doUpdate() {
        //some code
    }

    public function doDelete() {
        //some code
    }

}
```

controller.php

```
<?php

require "../models/model.php";

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    if(is_callable($action)) {
        $action();
    }
}

function registerSomething(){
    $model = new myClass();
    $model->setAttrOne($_POST['attrOne']);
    $model->setAttrTwo($_POST['attrTwo']);
    $return = $model->doInsert();
    echo $return;
}

function registerSomething2(){
    // more app logic code and other stuff
}
```

view.php -> this is most a pure html file with php extension

```
<div id="result"></div>
<form id="register" role="form" >
    <input type="text" id="attrOne" name="attrOne"/>
    <input type="text" id="attrTwo" name="attrTwo"/>
</form>

<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the script.JS

```
$('#register').submit(function() {
    var action = 'registerSomething';
    $.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize() + '&action='+action,
    url: '../controlllers/controller.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    })
    return false;
})
```

So, what do you think about this pattern? is this pattern efficient?
What is the best way to do ajax calls with a proper mvc pattern in php?
Is this a best practice?

Comment: Have you tried CakePHP ? have a look and I'm sure it will be more comfort for you

Comment: @FahedAlkaabi how would CakePHP be related to ANYTHING? It's an old an shitty framework.

Comment: @FahedAlkaabi I'd say, go look at Joomla for PHP MVC

Comment: It's a very bare bones approach at MVC, but you can certainly do it that way. It's simple and easy to grasp. There is no rule that says you have to use OOP with MVC or have to utilize some sort of framework or certain domain model patterns. You [split user interface interaction into three distinct parts](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html). So that's good. Whether it's efficient in the long term depends on other factors. You'll find out eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your goal was to specifically implement something MVC-like, then you have utterly failed. This setup has absolutely nothing to do with MVC. To be honest, it seems that you are way too inexperienced for tackling something like that.

If instead this is your first attempt in applying [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) on your code, then it's appropriate. Though, I still wouldn't put that type of code in the production.

My recommendation for you would be: stop trying to "do MVC" for now, and focus instead on improving your general understanding of web development.

You should google the following topics for PHP:

- url routing
- autoloading and PSR4
- difference between active record and data mapper pattern
- request abstraction